# Save state in Matlab function called from c#

Tags: c#, matlab, matlab-compiler

I´m trying to call a Matlab function from C# and that is not really a problem, the problem is that I need to keep state in the Matlab part in order to use the previous results in the next calculation. This state should only exist in the Matlab runtime.

[image]

I have tried to use globals without any luck in C#, and I guess that´s not a pretty solution at all or is it?

I also tried getmcruserdata/setmcruserdata but I can only make that work in Matlab not in C#.

I hope that someone has some input or even better some examples.

### Update

I tried the following approaches

**classdef**
But MabLab classes don´t seem to work in .Net

**global variable** (Did not work)

```
function y = stateCalc1(x)

global state
state = state + x;

y = state;
```

**persistent** (Did not work)

```
function y = statePersistent(x)

persistent state
state = state + x;

y = state;
```

**getmcruserdata/setmcruserdata** (Worked)

```
function y = stateCalc2(x)

val = getmcruserdata('data');

if (isempty(val))
    val = x;
else
    val = val + x;    
end

setmcruserdata('data',val);

y = val;
```

This **actually works** now, but I still don´t know if it´s the best approach?

**.Net/C#**

```
  var testClass = new TestClass();

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    MWArray input = i;
    result = testClass.stateCalc(input);

    var output = (MWArray)result;
    Console.WriteLine(output);
  }

  Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Some code would probably be helpful. Just a small example of a matlab function that needs to maintain state and the C# code you are using to call it (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Why does your state need to stay in Matlab?  Could you include the state values in your return function and pass your output (with state) as input to your next call to the Matlab function?

Comment: Apologize for the advertising but you might be able to remove the problem completely by using [ILNumerics](http://ilnumerics.net) and stay within C#, no?

Comment: @MattBurland I normally provide an example, but it´s a proof of concept and the function in Matlab could be x = x +1. I use the MATLAB Compiler SDK som in C# it´s again just calling a method. But I´ll make some examples.

Comment: @thinklarge The reason for having the state in the Matlab part is because there is one team providing the C# part and another team providing Matlab code, and the Matlab team would to able to store state in dynamic types and not be bound to.Net types. So the only contract would be the data transfer. I actually tried to store state in a Matlab class, so I could send it back in next calculation, but it did not work for me.

Comment: @HaymoKutschbach is has to be Matlab for this project, because the algorithms is developed in Matlab. But maybe in another project.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using MATLAB Compiler SDK to create the MATLAB Component here (or MATLAB Builder for .NET as it was known in older versions of MATLAB).

If so, it's really designed for deploying functionality that does not require state - you would typically deploy things with a purely function-based interface. If you have to store state, it's better if you can to do this on the .NET side.

You can use `persistent` variables to store state between function calls, but you need to be careful, as that variable will only remain persistent while the MCR stays up. If your call from .NET makes the MCR start up, carries out the function call, and then shuts the MCR down, the variable will not remain persistent across calls.

If you need to ensure that the MCR remains up, you can write a small .NET wrapper application that does nothing but start the MCR, and then pass through any calls from your main application (and shuts it down on exit). You may need to also worry about explicitly monitoring the MCR in case you cause it to crash (for example by causing it to run out of memory), and if it does so, bringing it back up.

Before you start down that route, though, take a look at [MATLAB Production Server](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/matlab-production-server). This is an add-on product designed to address some of the issues you'll end up facing, such as managing a pool of MCRs - it also does a lot more, though, and it is relatively expensive, so it may be overkill for your application.

Alternatively, you can always store state by writing and reading a file between function calls - this may be slow, though, depending on the size of your state.

Comment: You are right, it´s MATLAB Compiler SDK I am using. I know that I´m trying to fit a square into a round hole, but it could save some time and effort if we could try out Matlab algorithms in .Net without porting them to C#. I think that the MATLAB Production Server would be overkill. I will take a look at `persistent`, it´s not a problem that it only have state as long as the MCR is running, it´s only for testing not production. Another thing is that the MCR take a long time to spin up, is there a smart/easy way to "init" the MCR so the first call dont take forever (other than a dummy call) ??